# How to increase threads until error in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way in which you can increment the number of threads in a Jmeter test plan, with a new user every 5 seconds until an error occurs?

I have tried using Stepping Thread Group, but it seems like I have to provide the number of threads for the beginning, and it's not dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretical highest number of virtual users you can create with JMeter is [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647).

Practical amount for [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and other [TCP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/TCP)-based protocols is [65535](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,535#In_computing)

With normal JMeter [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) the [formula for the ramp-up](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) would be:

```
number of users - 1 * ramp-up period in seconds
```

which gives `19660200` ramp-up time.

Comment: Do you know if is there any way in which I can increase the number of threads in Stepping Thread Group without giving the number of threads in the beginning?

Comment: No, Stepping Thread Group needs to know the final number of threads in order to [schedule threads execution](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/threads/SteppingThreadGroup.java#L28). You might want to consider creating your own Thread Group implementation as a [new JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development)